# Django admin site lost all its formatting

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I change my computer and I migrated my django project just by copying the directory created by `django-admin create project` from the old computer to the new one. I installed all required modules in the new computer (including django) under a new Python virtual environment, and everything worked perfectly, but the admin site of the project, that shows in plain html with no styling at all.

I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened to me when I transferred the project to the production server for the first time. I don't know if you are using `runserver` or is your new computer hosting the project with Apache or Nginx. If it is the latter try the following command on the project root directory.

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Beware that you also need to specify the `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` in the `settings.py` file in order for the above command to work.

Refer to the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) in order to learn more about working with static files in Django.

Comment: It was the STATIC_ROOT. Thanks a lot